# Python - How to merge to df by an id and also get the NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, grouping, concatenation

## Python - How to merge two df by an id and also get the NaN values

I'm merging two df by id's. 
Problem is there are values with no id "NaN' but I still need to account on those.

---

#### how to get these values as well when merging

---

#### Im trying to assign a value like "12345" for them, to be able to bring the data, not sure if there is the best option.

```
# Dataframe

g_spend = 

    id   Campaign_ID   Month  campaignid   cost    
0 1664745    154      2019|08  31664745   $34.3    
1 NaN      2019|08  31664745   $34.3    65.0
2 1664745    154      2019|08  31664745   $34.3    
3            154      2019|08  31664745   $34.3    
4 1664745    154      2019|08  31664745   $34.3    



cw =

   id           leads
0 1664745       65.0   
2 1664745      65.0
4 1664745      65.0
```

#### works, but missing the NaN values and empty fields

```
#my attempt

grouped_cw= cw.groupby(["campaignid"]).sum()
grouped_cw = pd.DataFrame(grouped_cw)

g_spend = g_spend.merge(grouped_cw, left_on='campaignid', right_index=True)
```

Desired output

```
    id   Campaign_ID   Month  campaignid   cost    leads
0 1664745    154      2019|08  31664745   $34.3    65.0
1            NaN      2019|08  31664745   $34.3     65.0
2 1664745    154      2019|08  31664745   $34.3    65.0
3            154      2019|08  31664745   $34.3    65.0
4 1664745    154      2019|08  31664745   $34.3    65.0
```

Comment: Is the mangled data in index 1 of `g_spend` correct?

Comment: You're also attempting to group `cw` by `campaignid` but it doesn't have that column.

Comment: add a blank id to cw; then g_spend['id'].fillna("", inplace = True). It will link the blank id's... But you should have more than one key, because o.w. it will merge all blanks all the time and that's not what u want